# JavaScript - collapse element by changing class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a grid of nine boxes. On clicking any of those nine boxes, the one clicked, occupies the space of the entire grid, and displays some information within it. Now, I have also made a cross at the top right of every grid, which, on being clicked, is meant to collapse the grid to its original size and occupy its previous position. I have written the pure JavaScript code for it, and inspecting the code in the browser suggests there is nothing wrong with the code. But, my cross button doesn't seem to work.
Below, I have mentioned the JS functions I have written.
Here is the jsFiddle for it : https://jsfiddle.net/ag_dhruv/wx7en2kx/ 
And here is the folder containing my page : goo.gl/Qiafc7

```
function expand (x) {
var tester = x.className.substr(5,7);
if(tester != "ex"){
x.className = x.className+"ex";
var cross = x.getElementsByClassName('cross');
for (var i = 0; i < cross.length; i++) {
    cross[i].className = "crossshown";
};
var icon = x.getElementsByClassName('boxfortitle');
for (var j = 0; j < icon.length; j++) {
    icon[j].className = "boxfortitlebig";
};
var info = x.getElementsByClassName('info');
for (var k = 0; k < info.length; k++) {
    info[k].className = "infoshown";
};
x.id="opened";
}
}

function collapse (y) {
var classOfParent = y.parentNode.className;
var newClassName = classOfParent.substr(0,5);
y.parentNode.className = newClassName;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed yo use jquery?

Comment: @Carlitrosss , I would prefer **not** using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `collapse()` function your event is [Bubbling through the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) causing your `expand()` function to be called directly after your `collapse()` function has finished running. Because the onclick is called on the child element and then the onclick is called on the parent. So it opens itself again straight away.

Instead of passing `this` through to the `collapse()` pass the event object.

E.g `collapse(event);`

The event object has a function on it called [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) which will stop this happening if you call it at the bottom of your function.

```
function collapse (event) {
    var classOfParent = event.currentTarget.parentNode.className;
    var newClassName = classOfParent.substr(0,5);
    event.currentTarget.parentNode.className = newClassName;
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

When I tested this there are a few more visual things you need to do in mouse event. But hope this helps.

**Additional Info: Event Bubbling and Propagation**
This is my understanding. Bubbling and propagation are the same thing. Its all to do with how events move through the DOM. Think of an event like a bubble underwater, no matter how deep you are the bubble has to go to the surface.

```
<div onclick="onParentClick(event);">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="logo" onclick="onChildClick(event);" />
</div>
```

If you click on the Child `img` it calls it's `onclick` and once that method has finished the event ***(bubble underwater)*** has to make it to the `body` element ***(surface)***, so any `onclick` between itself and the `body` element will be called until it reaches the top. This only effects parents and children sibling events are not called. If you click ONLY the Parent `div` it follows the same procedure, but the Child `div` `onclick` is not called as bubbles only float upwards.

Each instance of an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) has a property called `bubbles`, a boolean, which tells you if the event is going to continue up the DOM tree.

You have three main ways to interact with your event instance to get it to do something other than its default behaviour.

`event.stopPropagation();` Stops the event bubbling up the DOM for this specific event. E.g Stopping propagation for `onclick` but not `mouseup`.

`event.stopImmediatePropagation();` Stops the event bubbling and any other event listener on that element. E.g Calling this method will stop an `mouseup` from firing after the `onclick`.

`event.preventDefault();` Stops default browser functionality. E.g If you want to stop the browser reacting to a `<a>` tag with your own `onclick` on it.

Comment: Great! Thanks a ton! Yes, I realized that there are a few more things I need to do. Cheers!!

Comment: Also, could you please explain what "Bubbling through the DOM" means? I opened the link, but could not understand what it says there!

Answer (score 2):

Found your bug.  `expand(this)` is bound to the **whole** box, so when you click the x, it calls collapse() and then expand(), resulting in no net change.

Your code is all over the place; cleaning up that should make this bug easy to fix.

Comment: Ahh, I somewhat get what you're saying. This is my first major project as a web designer, would you be able to suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

when you call expand every time you call collapse. You also need to pass "this" for all your collapse methods

edit your expand and add this to the beginning

```
if(x.getAttribute("id")!="opened"){
    ...
}
```

and this requires further logic edits.
**or**
use `onclick="collapse(this); event.stopPropagation();"` to prevent firing parent event

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand what's happening here. And yes, that I am aware I need to add "pass" for all the collapse methods. This was just a testing phase. Cheers! :D

Comment: Umm, when I am adding y.parentNode.id = "closed" at the end of the collapse function, the function does not work again, Any solution to that you could suggest?

Comment: every time "collapse" is called, "expand" will be also called in this order. So  y.parentNode.id = "closed" at the end of the collapse function will cause the expand condition to pass . This will take us back to the original problem

Comment: Oh okay, so if I want to make the icons expandable multiple times, this is not the method I should use.

Comment: Just use this trick onclick="collapse(this); event.stopPropagation();"... see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m15xybap/1/

Answer (score 0):

The click event on the cross element gets propagated to the parent element where it also triggers the click handler (expand). One way to solve the problem would be to stop event propagation.

```
<div class="cross" onclick="collapse(this); event.stopPropagation();" >
```

Comment: Oh, thank you SO much! This works. Could you please explain to me what event.stopPropagation(); does?

Comment: The answer of @Rick should point you into the right direction. While my proposed solution works, his is actually a bit nicer. You can find more information on event bubbling and propagation here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Thank you, this link was helpful. :D